# Anyway to prevent innerHTML/$.html from converting escaped characters?

Tags: jquery, escaping, innerhtml

Long time lurker, first time asker.

I am wondering if there is anyway to make innerHTML/jquery .html not convert escaped characters.

More specifically... I am trying to do the following:

```
$("#myid").html('<a href="javascript:;" onclick="myfunction(\''+a_lot_of_text+'\');" </a>')
```

Now, a_lot_of_text may have escaped quotes, double quotes, and the like ... however, $.html converts the `&quot;` into `"` which of course, screws up the code. Is there a "reasonable" way to insert the exact string I pass into an id?

Comment: jQuery + onclick attribute = you're doing it wrong

Comment: a_lot_of_text would be for example, someone's bio that may include ', ", or all kind of other characters. To those commenting on jQuery + onClick is wrong etc. The id does not exist when the page is first created (or may not exist) which is why I am using onclick.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use `innerText` or jQuery's `text()` method instead.

```
$('elem').text('&quot;');
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/g3qoy0gm/).

Also as you're using jQuery there's no need to use inline JavaScript. Replace your `onclick` handler with jQuery:

```
$('#myid').on('click', function() {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: I don't think this would work for a few reasons. (1) text will then escape all the other code I am inserting (which I do not need to be inserted). 92) using the onclick handler will not work because in my case the id is dynamically generated.